# How to write the integration test cases in Akka-HTTP services using sbt-scoverage?

Tags: scala, testing, integration-testing, akka-http

Can anyone suggest how can I write the `integration` tests in `Akka-HTTP` services using `sbt-scoverage`. I have written unit test cases now I need to implement integration tests.

This is my route

```
val routes = {
    logRequestResult("microservice") {
      path("test") {
        (post) {
          complete {
            find().map { v => 
              var info = convertToJson(v) 
              HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/json`), info.getOrElse(Json.obj()).toString))
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and my model class method is

```
    def find()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[Details]] = {
  collection.find(BSONDocument()).one[Details]
```

}

can u suggest how to write `integration tests` for above route

Answer (score 2):

sbt-scoverage is used for measuring the test coverage of your code. It is not used for writing test cases. You can use Akka-Http test kit for writing test cases.

Go through the documentation of akka-http they've very well explained it: [Akka-Http TestKit](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/testkit.html)